# normal distribution calculation based on set of questions

Tags: probability

A study examined efficiency of a gene which is used to treat diabetes patients. A reduction of sugar level is observed μ =0.7% with deviations of σ =1%. Assumption is normal distribution and representing population.
Why mean and SD in percentage. And need help to calculate below mentioned questions.

A: What percentage of the population wouldn’t have the reduction (reduction less than 0%)

B) What percentage of the population would have a reduction between 0.7% and 1.0%?

C) Generate a sample of 10 patients of the population with a sugar reduction, estimates the mean of the sample with a confidence interval of 99%. Describe the results.

D) Generate a sample of 150 patients of the population with a sugar reduction, and estimate the mean with a confidence interval of 99%. Justify the differences between the last index.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion..